# isalnum() in python is testing for True for all strings from a list

Tags: python, string

Here is a simple code block. I'd like to test each element in the list to see if it contains an Alpha Numeric character for further processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

words = ["cyberpunk" ,"x10", "hacker" , "x15" , "animegirl" , "x20"]
for x in words:
        print x + " / " +  str(x.isalnum())
```

Unforunately this gives me this output:

```
cyberpunk / True
x10 / True
hacker / True
x15 / True
animegirl / True
x20 / True
```

However if I test it as lets say:

```
x = "x10"
print x.isalnum()
x = "this sucks" 
print x.isalnum()
```

I get the right result!

```
True
False
```

What's the different between the List strings and the standalone strings?

Comment: Why is the first output incorrect? All those strings are alphanumeric

Comment: "What's the different between the List strings and the standalone strings?" That the standalone string you tested has a non alphanumeric character in it (the white space).

Comment: I would like things like cyberpunk to be false. There are no numbers in that string!

So i'll have to build this with the position of characters in the string with isalpha then.

Comment: why people are down-voting this question. This is a serious issue in python that isalnum() returns True on letters only and also on alpha numeric

Answer (score 4):

You seem to think `isalnum` returns True if a string contains both letters and numbers. What it actually does is return True if the string is *only* letters or numbers. Your last example contains a space, which is not a letter or number.

You can build up the functionality you want:

```
words = ["cyberpunk" ,"x10", "hacker" , "x15" , "animegirl" , "x20", "this sucks"]

def hasdigit(word):
    return any(c for c in word if c.isdigit())

def hasalpha(word):
    return any(c for c in word if c.isalpha())

def hasalnum(word):
    return hasdigit(word) and hasalpha(word)

for word in words:
        print word,'/',hasalnum(word)
```

Output:

> ```
> cyberpunk / False
> x10 / True
> hacker / False
> x15 / True
> animegirl / False
> x20 / True
> this sucks / False
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your string that fails contains a space character.  None of the entries in the list contains a space.

Comment: there is no space in the list of words

Comment: Yes, which is why every entry in the list returns True.  The example that fails is further down in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Just a discussion as I am suffering from same issue!

**According to Python 2.7 Documentation**

> [str.**isalnum()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) 
>                 Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

**According to Python 3.6.6 Documentation**

> [str.**isalnum()**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) 
>                 Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise. A character `c` is alphanumeric if one of the following returns `True`: `c.isalpha()`, `c.isdecimal()`, `c.isdigit()`, or `c.isnumeric()`.

Here are few tests for `isalnum()` in python v3.6.6

```
>>> "alpha".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha10".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha%&@".isalnum()
False
>>> "alpha %&@".isalnum()
False
>>> "alpha with space".isalnum()
False
```

In first test `"alpha".isalnum()` returns `True`

And in `isalpha()` test, results are like this:

```
>>> "alpha".isalpha()
True
>>> "alpha10".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha%&@".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha %&@".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha with space".isalpha()
False
```

So the problem is that `isalnum()` and `isalpha()` both returns `True` when a string contains only characters

```
>>> "alpha".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha".isalpha()
True
```

Results are positive if we combine `isalnum()` and `isalpha()` checks to find out alphanumeric on your given list

```
words = ["cyberpunk" ,"x10", "hacker" , "x15" , "animegirl" , "x20"]
for s in words:
    if s.isalpha() and s.isalnum():
        print(s,"is NOT alphanumeric")
    else:
        print(s, "is alphanumeric")
```

**Output:**

```
cyberpunk is NOT alphanumeric
x10 is alphanumeric
hacker is NOT alphanumeric
x15 is alphanumeric
animegirl is NOT alphanumeric
x20 is alphanumeric
```

But the above algorithm will fail on following list of words:

```
words = ["with space", "speci@lChar", "140"]
```

and the Output is:

```
with space is alphanumeric
speci@lChar is alphanumeric
140 is alphanumeric
```

**Conclusion**

As explained in the [python 3.6.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum), we need to check each character of a word and if any of the given condition fails, a word will not be considered as alphanumeric

---

**Edited**

Following algorithm can help us by checking each character

```
words = ["cyberpunk" ,"x10", "hacker" , "x15" , "animegirl" , "x20", "with space", "speci@lChar", "140"]
for word in words:
    isAlpha = False
    isNum = False
    for c in word:
        if c.isalpha():
            isAlpha = True
        elif c.isdigit():
            isNum = True
        else:
            isAlpha = isNum = False
            break
    if isAlpha and isNum:
        print(word, "is alphanumeric")
    else:
        print(word, "is NOT alphanumeric")
```

**Output:**

```
cyberpunk is NOT alphanumeric
x10 is alphanumeric
hacker is NOT alphanumeric
x15 is alphanumeric
animegirl is NOT alphanumeric
x20 is alphanumeric
with space is NOT alphanumeric
speci@lChar is NOT alphanumeric
140 is NOT alphanumeric
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [isalnul](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum).

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there >is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

Then as all the characters of the list `words` are alphanumeric (single letters or numbers) `isalnum` returns True for all.

In `this sucks` we have the character "" (blank space) that is not alphanumeric. Then `isalnum` returns us `False`

```
' '.isalnum() #Return False
```

If you want to find out whether or not they have numbers you can do something like this:

```
from string import digits

def have_numbers(s):
    for digit in digits:
        if digit in s:
            return True
    return False

have_numbers("cyberpunk") # return False
have_numbers("x10") # return True
```

Comment: This answers part of the question --- why `isalnum` returned `False` for `"this sucks"`.  You did not answer the first part --- why `isalnum` got the "wrong" answer for strings in the list.  (For the record, I did not downvote you, but I'm guessing that's why someone else did.)

Comment: Thank you @kevin-j-chase . Improved response!

Answer (score -1):

there are a nice code for similar case

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
s = input()
for method in [str.isalnum, str.isalpha, str.isdigit, str.islower, str.isupper]:
    print(any(method(c) for c in s))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).